# IntelliJ Code Style for Scala Templates

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.4, scala-template

I'm having trouble with IntelliJ's auto-formatting for Scala templates (.scala.html files). I tried to modify the settings for HTML, but they don't seem to have any effect. It seems that when I have a pure HTML file, those settings work just fine.

I have searched here, but I've seen some answers that are very old (2012 or 2013) stating that the issue will be fixed, but I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ and when I run "reformat code", it messes up the style of the code.

Thank you